# Google analytics : Multi events goals processed as only 1 Goal

Tags: google, analytics, conversions

I'm trying to integrate Dave McClure Pirate metrics into my google analytics data measurment model.

I'd like to create a goal named 
"Activation" 
and this goal could be

[Visitor >10 sec] or [Signup to newsletter] or [contacted us] or [Page views >=3]

I'd like that if one of them is verified it counts only for 1 (ie: if a visitor stays 19 sec on my website and signs to the newsletter, i'd only like to count as 1 conversion)

Do you know if these options are available in google analytics ?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is not available via the Google Analytics interface - Goals are either destinations or visit duration or pageview, but alas they cannot have, at the moment at least, multiple criteria or conditions in the criteria.

One way around is to have separate goals for each criteria and then create a segment that includes only visitors that have met all three goals (actually you could skip goals entirely and set the criteria in your segment definition). The number of visits in that segment gives you the conversions for your combined goal.

Another way is to track pageviews and visits on the client site, send an event when your conditions are met - then you could create an event based goal. This requires some programming and personally I do not think it's worth the trouble - personally I'd go for segments.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an Advanced Segment from the Admin Panel or Segment Dashboard, then simply activate it and look at the Events reports (obviously, you should also create Events for signups and contact forms).

[image: Advanced segments for multiple behaviors and events conditions in Google Analytics]

As you can see, you can set everything you need from the Conditions tab.

Just Time on Site is different, because you can't set a number in seconds or a real number. It should be an integer. But saying more than 10 seconds is like saying "not a bounce\more than 0".

At the end I chose Event Label, but you can also choose Event Category or Event Action, it depends on what you need.

[image: Activate an Advanced Segment in Google Analytics in Goal Reports]

Comment: This is awesome thank you very much i'm trying to build it right now.

Comment: my pleasure, let me know

Comment: It's working really well thanks. 
I just wonder if those Advanced segment are treated as "conversions". 

I mean is it possible to retreive those segments and use them to identify if  (for ex) a google adwords campaign has a great Activation rate ( with activation = your first picture example ).

I am not sure to understand your last picture this is why i ask

Thanks !!

Comment: A segment is a bucket of visitor that satisfy specific conditions. In this case, if a user satisfy one of those 4 conditions, it's counted as 1, and everyone who don't satisfy any condition is discarded. After you apply the segment, you see a % number under the name of it. That's the rate of people that are in the segment in relation to the total number of visitors. So, you can consider it as a "conversion rate". But the interesting thing is that you can see how this segment behaves on the website using all the reports.

Comment: Anyway  I want to suggest that considering this kind of behavior as a unique conversion/segment is strange. Each of these conditions can be part of a total different behavior. For example, first condition (not a bounce) is for everyone that navigates the website, so they could be not interested in any kind of mailing list. Just segment people by intention, actual behavior, demographics etc. Something like a segment for "people who are engaged above the average" (conditions like page depth), and another one like "people interested in our proposal" (contact and newsletter event) is an example.

Comment: Hey,
Ok i start to understand :) I really need to use this data to manage my adwords account not only to see it in the reports. 
I'll try to see if i can have

Adwords campaign > Impression > CTR > Bouncerate > conversion rate of acquisition / Activation etc...

i hope i will :))